# Android : How to avoid Null pointer exception in Helper class?

Tags: java, android, view, textview

i would like to set some info into textView component from method in helperClass (extended from Activity), but i always get null pointer exception if i'm trying to work with textView.

```
  TextView stateTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
```

How can i do it correctly in simple  Helper class?

In main and others activities is it working.

Thanks for any advice.

Example included:

```
   /**
     * Set actual position to textview
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void setPositionToView (Context ctx) {
        try {

            // HERE I GET NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
            TextView stateTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state);
            stateTv.setText(R.string.position_is_set);
            stateTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(AppHelper.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "setPositionToView method cannot be processed", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: show your full class code and crash log?

Comment: `Helper class`  is normal java class or extending Activity? if normal class then you also need to add one more Activity context parameter to `setPositionToView`. then use activity context to initialize stateTv TextView instance

Comment: Show xml where you define `Textview` with id `state`.

Comment: Where do you inflate the container for that TextView?

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/state"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Position is not set"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginTop="159dp"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

Comment: Error message:
 java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1882)
            at com.car.finder.AppHelper.setPositionToView(AppHelper.java:209)
            at com.car.finder.GpsHelper.onLocationChanged(GpsHelper.java:148)

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
if( stateTv != null ) {
   ...
```

bit it looks that this layout should have this widget, so if your app crashes, fix the layout as that'd be the proper approach. Also there's no information about in what context you are trying to look for the widget (maybe this is wrong view).